# Angular AOT unexpected behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular2-aot

*This comes from a similar error that I encountered on one of my projects, but since it's fixed, I just want to know why it happens.*

In Typescript, when using a constant string enum, it gets compiled either to a string, or an object that has a property that is that string.

[See an example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20enum%20something%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somestr%3D%20%22hello!%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.innerText%20%3D%20something.somestr%3B)

[And another one here](https://codepen.io/raidenfreeman/pen/wjrVQo). *(To see the compiled JS, click on the arrow next to JS(Typescript) and select "View Compiled JS")*

When using a const enum value, at least if you AOT optimize your angular build, the enum gets completely discarded and replaced by strings.

[Check out this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaqcuy)

As you will see, it works fine in stackblitz, because it gets compiled without optimizations.

If you download it, and build it with `ng build --prod`, because it also activates `--build-optimizer` and `--aot`, the deployed build will crash at runtime.

This is a simple example found at [angular.io's animations documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations).

What I have modified is in /src/app/hero-list-basic.component.ts , **lines 15, 44, 48, 60**.

If you look into the compiled JS bundle, you will see that the enum is not defined anywhere. That happens irrespectively to existing refernces (as you can see in the constructor at line 60). Apparently, the build just inline replaces the enum with the respective string, just like the TS compiler in TS Playground.

My problem is that in the decorator (`@Component`), you will see that instead of being inlined, it is null. The location in my bundle.js is ~line 6557.

[image]
*(the line with `name: "active"` @ line 6569 has a value, because I haven't changed it at that build from a string to an enum, ignore it)*

---

### Is this a bug with the TS compiler, with the AOT compiler, some webpack plugin (for minification/uglification), or am I just stupid for looking into this so much? Thank you in advance for your input!

Comment: I came across the same problem. Very annoying, because the error message is not helpful at all. It took me some time to even figure out that it is caused by the enum. Anyway. I found an angular bug report about this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24047. It's still open at this time. A quick fix is to add export to the enum. Still doesn't explain why and how that error happens.

Answer (score -1):

The Angular Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler converts your Angular HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase before the browser downloads and runs that code.

An Angular application consists largely of components and their HTML templates. Before the browser can render the application, the components and templates must be converted to executable JavaScript by an Angular compiler.

Angular offers two ways to compile your application:

Just-in-Time (JIT), which compiles your app in the browser at runtime
Ahead-of-Time (AOT), which compiles your app at build time.

JIT compilation is the default when you run the build-only or the build-and-serve-locally CLI commands:

ng build
ng serve

For AOT compilation, append the --aot flags to the build-only or the build-and-serve-locally CLI commands:

content_copy
ng build --aot
ng serve --aot

Source: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

after AOT compilation, You entire ts (ES6) code will be converted into plain javascript that time your enum also gets converted. here your value is null. It is trying to convert that enum value by calling

.toString().
Here in your case it is 
null.toString()

so throwing error.

Comment: Thank you, I do know all that; the problem is that it is weird to not be converted to an inline string, and instead call an object, which is kind of reasonably null.